# Change arraylist to generic

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-3.5

I am using below code :

```
            var list = new Collection<ArrayList>
                       {
                           new ArrayList
                               {
                                   1,
                                   "Test1"
                               },
                           new ArrayList
                               {
                                   2,
                                   "Test2"
                               },
                       };
```

In the above code I want to avoid the ArrayList and use the Generics. Is it possible in the above code?

Edit:
Above I have used only two values in one arraylist object, I may have multiple items of int's and string's in it.

Comment: You should replace your `ArrayList`s with a custom `class`/`struct`/`Tuple<>`/etc. It will be much more readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't mix types in a generic list (unless the generic type is `object`, but that equates to `ArrayList` and is just a perversion of generics).

But you can create a class that contains a `string` and `int` and use that as the generic parameter for a generic list.

```
public class MyClass
{
 public MyString string { get; set; }
 public MyInt int { get; set; }
}

var list = new Collection<MyClass>
           {
             new MyClass { MyInt = 1, MyString = "Test1" },
             new MyClass { MyInt = 2, MyString = "Test2" }
           }
```

Another alternative, if using .NET 4.0 is to use a [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx), though I would rather have a strongly typed class.

(untested code):

```
 var list = new Collection<Tuple<int,string>>
           {
             Tuple.Create(1, "Test1"),
             Tuple.Create(2, "Test2")
           }
```

Comment: Passing this class to JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list) will produce key/value pairs which I am trying to avoid in my case as I need only values like [1,"Test1"],[2,"Test2"]

Comment: Thanks, but I am using .NET 3.5 and what if I am having more than 2 values say int, string, int , int

Comment: @Rocky - I only mentioned .NET 4.0 for other readers and for completeness. In your case, I would still use a custom class - you can add attributes to the different properties in order to control serialization.

Comment: "add attributes to the different properties in order to control serialization" I think you are about to hit the nail :) How can I do the same to stop the property names coming in output of serialization?

Comment: @Rocky - not sure, but take a look at the [`DataMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) documentation and the other classes in that namespace.

Comment: @Rocky - another option is to write your own serializer based on `JavaScriptSerializer`. You _can_ inherit from it.

Comment: @Oded let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2109/discussion-between-rocky-singh-and-oded)

Answer (score 4):

No.
The whole point of generics is that you can't put an `int` and a `string` in the same collection.

Instead, you should create your own class with `int` and `string` properties, then create a generic collection of that class.

Comment: Thanks, I thought in the same way but on serialization key/value pair was coming .i.e key was the property name and value is the value of the property. I just want the values only in comma separated form after serialization like [1,"Test1"],[2,"Test2"]

Comment: Huh? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Passing this class to JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list) will produce key/value pairs

Comment: I see.  Then you can only use an `ArrayList` or `List<object>`

Answer (score 2):

Not really, the fact that you have different types makes using a generic pointless.

You could use `List<object>` instead of ArrayList but there's really no point.  Instead you could create a custom class to hold the 2 values and use that in a generic type.

John

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need Dictionary?

```
var list = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 1, "Test1" },
    { 2, "Test2" }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List < Dictionary<int, string>> ();
```

then you can populate it was data as you need.

Comment: What if I have more than 2 values ?

Comment: at this stage you will need to create a custom class for it, but for your case, this will work effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are actually trying to achieve, but it seems to me you are trying to mimic the behavior of a **dictionary** or **map**, that can map two different values to each other. These values could be of any type you want.

Something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
d.Add(1, "Test1");
d.Add(2, "Test2");
```

and you can handle your data as simple as:

```
string t1 = d[1];    //will hold "Test1"
string t2 = d[2];    //will hold "Test2"
```

Do you want something like this?